# How to reference two similar files and sign them to be side-by-side?

Tags: c#, csc

I have a problem that you might be able to solve I want to reference two files that are somewhat similar and let's say their names are ReferenceA.exe and ReferenceB.exe, They both do do similar things,

and when I try to compile it with C Sharp Compiler (or csc in command prompt).

It gives me this error:

> ReferenceA.exe: error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name ReferenceA, Version=1.3.3.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side.
>
> ReferenceB.exe: (Location of symbol related to previous error)

I am having trouble with this error because I need to reference ReferenceB to my project WITH ReferenceA

But, However I am curious about signing them to run side by side.
Do you know how to do that? if so please answer this question.

Comment: have u tried what Gregor Primar said in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001185/assembly-same-simple-name-already-been-imported-error

Comment: This cannot come to a good end at runtime.  One reference assembly is going to overwrite the other so somebody is going to lose.  These assemblies need to be installed in the GAC so the code can get the version of the type they need at runtime.  That requires first signing them.  Very easy to do with Project > Properties > Signing tab.  Use `extern alias` so you can reference them both in one project.  Or consider moving the code that needs B into another project, YMMV.

Comment: Alright I'll look into that @HassanAtaUllah

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same name to your Reference. Rename one of your assembly and recompile.

Or you can choose the strong name for your same assembly with two different version.

```
Project Properties --> Signing (tab)
```