# An assembly with the same simple name 'IdentityModel' has already been imported.Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, identityserver4, openid-connect

Can somebody help me understand the root cause of the following exception? I don't understand how this can happen, because it refers to a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) that I consume.

> An assembly with the same simple name 'IdentityModel' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g. 'C:\Users\ {MYUSERNAME}\ .nuget\packages\identitymodel/3.7.0.\lib/netstandard2.0/IdentityModel.dll') or sign them to enable side-by-side.
>
> 1. @using {MYPROJECT.NAMESPACE}.ViewModels.Sport
> 2. @model List < WorkoutViewModel >
> 3. @{
> 4. ViewBag.Title = "Workouts";
> 5. }

The exception points to lines of code of one of my views. The code is triggered through an integration test using NUnit.

IdentityModel is a nuget package, so I basically have no control over it.

Deleting the IdentityModel.dll at the specified path had no effect, because it gets restored by the nuget package manager and the same exception will be thrown.

So I followed the second advice of the exception and it worked, but I am not satisfied with this workaround:

1. Download the source code from https://github.com/IdentityModel
2. Open the downloaded source code in a completely different solution
3. Sign the IdentityModel project in its project settings
4. Compile it
5. Replace the IdentityModel.dll at the specified path mentioned in the exception with my own signed and compiled IdentityModel.dll

However, I fear that I have to do this now for every new release of this nuget package, or at least whenever I decide to update it. I would like to avoid this exception in a proper way in the first place.

Comment: Have you visited this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001185/assembly-same-simple-name-already-been-imported-error

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I actually don't want to handle it in this way, because it requires me to maintain the source code. To move forward, I decided to solve it in this way. But still, I am not the creator nor a contributor and I only want to use this affected library through the nuget package manager.